# Fill color in 2D Animation

Tags: 2d

i'm in 2D animation - Draw mode,
I've set up world color in yellow.
But when I fill pink into my drawing, it shows different color to my material color.
How can I solve this?
Thank you in advance :)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Layers properties and uncheck the "Use lights" option.

[image]